# How to use colorbrewer in pgf area plot

Tags: pgfplots, color

I am trying to create an area chart using some colorbrewer color scheme.
How would I do that?
The things I found on the internet were somehow not working for area charts.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

% package for plots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest,
    width=455pt,
    height=5cm,
}

% command for plotting a given file
\newcommand{\plotfile}[1]{
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{#1}{\table}
    \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\table}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\numberofcols{\pgfplotsretval-1}
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,\numberofcols}{
        \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{##1}\of{\table}\to{\colname}
        \addplot table [y index=##1] {\table}
        \closedcycle;
        \addlegendentryexpanded{\colname}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0,
        xmax=100,
        domain=0:100,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=10000,
        xlabel=Generation,
        ylabel=Anzahl an Kreaturen,
        axis x line*=none,
        axis y line*=none,
        xtick={0,25,...,100},
        ytick={0,1000,...,10000},
        tick align=outside,
        xticklabel style={
            rotate=90,
            anchor=near xticklabel
        },
        legend style={
            at={(0.5,1.2)},
            legend columns=8,
            anchor=south,
            draw=none
        },
        smooth,
        stack plots=y,
        area style
        ]
        \plotfile{data.csv}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way you could do this. Because you didn't provide your data file I added some dummy data.

Please note that I removed everything unrelated from the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % load the colorbrewer library
    \usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        stack plots=y,
        % load a colorbrewer cycle list
        cycle list/Paired,
        % things to add to every `\addplot` ...
        every axis plot post/.style={
            % ... where we add the `fill` which by default is empty
            fill=.!50,
            % (this is just to show the borders a bit better)
            very thick,
        },
        % adjust the legend style accordingly for the area plots
        area legend,
        % show the axes on top of the plots
        axis on top,
    ]
        % some dummy data table because you didn't provide your data file
        \addplot table {
            x   y1  y2
            1   2   3
            2   3   4
        } \closedcycle;

        \addplot table {
            x   y1  y2
            1   2   3
            2   3   4
        } \closedcycle;

        \legend{a,b}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you so much! You were a bit too late though, as I found it out on my own and was just about to write my own answer xD. I read the pgfplots manual and it said the area charts use the same color palette as the bar charts do. From then on it was clear. Still, thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. Having a look at the manual is always a good idea ;)